# useEffect() and Google Firebase onAuthStateChange

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

Whenever the component mounts, onAuthStateChange(setCurrentUser) will be called, where a function to set the state of currentUser is passed in. Firebase then returns an authentication object depending on whether a user is signed in, which I use to set the state of currentUser as well as save the data in firestore using createUserDocument().

What does auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth ....) return? I am confused as its returned value is assigned to unsubscribe, which is called whenever the component unmounts.

```
function onAuthStateChange(callback) {
  return auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
    if (userAuth) {
      const userRef = await createUserDocument(userAuth); 
      userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
        callback({
          id: snapShot.id, 
          ...snapShot.data()
        })
      })
    } else {
      callback(null); 
    }
  })
}

function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null); 
  useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange(setCurrentUser); 
      return () => {
        unsubscribe(); 
      }; 
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) `onAuthStateChanged` returns `firebase.Unsubscribe`. When you call this function, Firebase makes sure that this request is removed from the Observables (so firebase does not notify your component that is no longer in and this prevents errors or memory leaks or wasted computing power).

Observables are implemented internally for Firebase and that's how they decide who requested a notification when a certain state changes.